# Can I make Roku app using flutter? if I Can how can I run

Tags: flutter, roku

I want to make a Roku app using flutter but don't know how can i run Roku app in flutter using android studio

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.
The only similarity Roku has with Android is Linux in its roots :)

To make Flutter work for Roku, you will need at least to add the possibility to display Skia canvas on the platform. To do so, most likely you will need NDK because BrightScript is poor for such purposes.

When I was working with Roku, NDK was not in public access, you had to write them directly via email to ask for it. And if Flutter SDK for Roku exists, you will still need to ask Roku to use NDK in your app because you will need it at least to initialize the project.

So yes, if one day an initiative exists, both Flutter and Roku teams will need to make efforts to make this idea alive. Btw, there is a request for Roku support to the Flutter team created in 2019: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37159